# Maintain Dynamic HTML made with jquery after form validation triggers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, frontend

I have this table in which I am able to generate rows for through a jquery click event.

Is it possible to keep my dynamic html after the pages model validation triggers with just the basic jquery library or should I use something else like ajax or the like in my MVC project?

Comment: what do you mean "keep my dynamic html"? Do you mean over a page load?

Comment: Please explain you question more?

Comment: sorry, forgot the details again.

I mean after page validation triggers.

I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, keep that state after a form has been submitted, you'll need to save that HTML fragment somehow e.g in a $_SESSION variable and then reload it on the next page.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I forgot to mention this is an ASP.NET MVC question. I forgot MVC's been used in PHP for a lot longer... Sorry

Comment: I don't know ASP, but surely it has a similar command to session i.e whatever you'd use for storing user credentials between pages etc. Principle is the same use a $.post()command to send the HTML fragment to a script which saves it and then reloads on the next page.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comment. I think I'll try storing the html text in a hidden field or something then.